# Fastest way to find an integer in array of integers without sorting and multithreading

Tags: java, arrays, search

This question was asked before and looked that without sorting and multithreading one simply needs to iterate through all elements.  Is there any other idea?  Java implementation is fine

Comment: Why do you have these restrictions?

Comment: just the task was given

Comment: If there is a restriction on the values of integers you can do something a bit faster, but generally no this is the optimal time case which is passing through the whole array.

Comment: @anarinsky If this is homework, you have to provide us what you've done, what you've thought about, etc. We can't do your thinking for you.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no other prerequisites for the input array, then no: You have to iterate through all the elements until you find the one you are looking for (thus, in worst and average case that would be `O(n)`).

If you have something else (like a heap, a search tree or any otherwise sorted array) you can use smarter and much faster techniques, of course (e.g. binary search).